# MySQL statement that returns only rows with exact equal amounts per ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Table `t1`

```
id | provider
_________
1  | bob
1  | ted

2  | bob
2  | bob
2  | ted
2  | ted

3  | bob
3  | bob
3  | ted
3  | ted
3  | joe
3  | joe

4  | bob
4  | bob
4  | ted
4  | joe
4  | joe
```

MySQL statement that returns id's where all names show up in equal amount per ID. For ID 4, the name "ted" shows up only once where the other names show up twice, so it would be excluded from the results.

```
id
__
1
2
3
```

Comment: What is your primary key?

Comment: pid, sorry I left that out of the table.

Comment: An Edit button is provided

Answer (score 0):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
select id
from (select id, name, count(*) as cnt
      from t1
      group by id, name
     ) ni
group by id
having min(cnt) = max(cnt);
```